# Translating propositional formulas

Tags: propositional-calculus

I've been given statements to translate into a propositional formula. The question states that it may also be possible for a statement to have multiple interpretations.

I've having trouble determining whether or not this is the case for the following statement, due to the word "when":
"I wear a coat when it's cold"

Let $w$ = "I wear a coat"; $c$ = "It's cold".

This might mean that both are simply happening at the same time, and thus I might interpret it as
$(w \land c)$.

However, another possibility could be that "when" acts as a conditional operator, and thus it could be interpreted as $(c \implies w)$, where $c$ is a condition for $w$.

But is this really a proper interpretation of the word "when"?

Comment: The term "when" has to do with tense.  I would translate the above by (c⟹w), but it does seem somewhat forced.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In my reading, yes (but please be aware of the fact that English is not my first language).

In this sentence, we want to express that "I wear a coat" is enforced by "It is cold". In natural language, we could also say:

> I wear a coat *whenever* it is cold.

or indeed:

> I wear a coat *if* it is cold.

So, for all intents and purposes, $c \implies w$ is an appropriate translation of our sentence.

Its truth/validity in the sense of a logical system will depend on the properties of this logical system (whether it "recognises time", and perhaps other properties).

---

Of course, this only applies to the particular use of "when" under discussion. It evidently doesn't work with "When does it get cold?" or even "I take a shower when I come home." Linguistically, it's probably to do with "it's cold" being a *condition* instead of a *time specification*.